# Heroku doesn't see gem 'pg'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dbmigrate

Need help.

When I try to make
`user@X220:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ heroku run rake db:migrate`

There is a mistake:

> Running rake db:migrate on limitless-fjord-69900.... up, run.2816
>   rake aborted!
>   Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded.
>   Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in`spec'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in`block (2 levels) in '
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in`execute_hook'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`each'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in`'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:8:in`'
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

My Gemfile is:

```
'source 'https://rubygems.org'  
ruby '2.2.0'  
gem 'activerecord', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.6'  
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'  
group :development, :test do  
    gem 'byebug'  
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.11'  
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.8'  
end  
group :test do  
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'  
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'  
end  
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'  
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'  
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'  
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby  
gem 'jquery-rails'  
gem 'turbolinks'  
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'  
group :doc do  
  gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', require: false   
end   
gem 'unicorn'  
group :development do  
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'  
  gem 'spring'  
end  
group :production do  
  gem 'rails_12factor'  
  gem 'pg'  
end
```

What's wrong?

Comment: use `pg` gem instead of `sqlite`.For more details read this document https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4#postgres

Comment: This may be obvious but did you run $bundle insall    to update it?

Comment: @Udaykumardas I added  `pg` instead of `sqlite3` in development. No changes.

Comment: @bkunzi01 I made of course installing and updating many times after almost each change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove or comment `gem 'sqlite3'` from your `Gemfile` even if it in `development` group.
I don't know why but Heroku doesn't run your application when it contains `sqlite` gem outside production.

If you are use SQLite in development, you have to comment `gem 'sqlite'` every time when deploying to Heroku and uncomment after deploying.
Better way will be use Postgres in development.

Comment: How to uncomment on Heroku `gem 'sqlite'` after deploying? Or to do this just in my code?

Comment: Yes, uncomment it only locally. Not deploy uncommented sqlite to Heroku.

Comment: The decision was to renew Gemfile, to delete `sqlite3`, to add `pg` into `production` and `default`. Thanks for a good hint!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested before, this could have to do with your `sqlite` gem.

If you still want to use `sqlite` you can set to ignore that group. From Heroku docs:

> To specify groups of gems to not to be installed, you can use the `BUNDLE_WITHOUT` config var.

```
$ heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"
```

Comment: Need I to do the command before `herokku run rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: @avzah: Yes you need to run it before.

Comment: @avzah: Actually that might only work when you make a deployment. Let me know how it went in either case.

Comment: adding `pg` to `default group` and `production group`, deleting`sqlite` - solved the problem. Thanks for good advice!